# CapnProto encodes string twice

Tags: capnproto

I have a simple `struct` containing some stuff, and also a `Text` field. I was looking at the result of encoding this data using Capnp, and for some reason the value of the text field appears in the encoded output *twice*! That doesn't seem very efficient or sane. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Cap'n Proto does not encode text fields twice. To understand what happened in your case, we'd need to see your code.